# Send continuous data via bluetooth while button pressed

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, arduino, ontouchlistener

I want to send data via bluetooth while a button is pressed. I am using an ontouchlistener. After the button down event happens the data transfer is started but when the button up event happens the transfer is not stopped immediately. At the bluetooth receiver side I see a lot of data incoming still after the button is released for a specific amount of time.

I tried to solve this issue with an flag which is evaluate in a while statement in the called methode. But this brings me to the above descriped issue.

Then I tried to solve this via an additional thread which is killed during the button up event. But the result did not changed.

Here is my code. Maybe somebody can help me.

```
mButtonMoveRight.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        moveRight p = new moveRight();
        Thread th = new Thread(p);

        switch(event.getAction())
        {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                pressed_right = true;
                th.start();
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                pressed_right = false;
                th.interrupt();
                break;
        }
            return false;
    }
});


private class moveRight implements Runnable
{

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);

        while (pressed_right == true) {
            if (btSocket != null) {
                try {
                    btSocket.getOutputStream().write("r".toString().getBytes());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    msg("Error");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't really know, but it seems to me two possibilities: 1. Your app is sending into the Stream faster than your arduino can read, so when you release the button, there will be still "r"'s in your connection to read by the arduino. 2. There is a delay, because the data is being transferred and is still arriving to your arduino. Can you check this two things?